# Regex: Abrir e fechar com o mesmo caractere e permitir mais de um tipo

Tags: regex, match

É possível obter um texto entre dois caracteres que sejam iguais, com as seguintes condições:

- O caractere de abertura deve ser o mesmo que o de fechamento.
- Permita mais de um tipo de caractere na abertura/fechamento.

Exemplo simples:

`/("|')asdasd("|')/`

Me permite pegar `"asdasd"` e `'asdasd'`

Porém ele também pega `"asdasd'`

Como fazer com que quando é aberto com `"`, permitir fechar apenas com `"`?

Comment: Mas `{` e `}` não são o mesmo caractere, se fosse `{asdasd{` seria fácil. Tens de criar uma função que compare o `unicode`. Quantos pares possíveis vais usar?

Comment: Sim realmente, foi só um mau exemplo que eu usei. E se os caracteres fossem `"` e `'`? – Como que funcionaria a função que você citou?

Comment: Não vejo porque o exemplo seja mau, imagino facilmente casos em que isto seja util. Em relação à pergunta `'`/`"`, queres dizer que no inicio terias `"` e no fim `'` ou seria o mesmo no inicio e fim? (e viste a minha pergunta: _"Quantos pares possíveis vais usar?"_)

Comment: Digo mau exemplo a fim de simplicidade para pergunta. Se no inicio for `"`, deve terminar com o mesmo, e o mesmo para `'`. Nunca começando com `"` e terminando com `'`. Eu vou usar 5 pares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar `\1` para garantir o uso do mesmo caracter que num grupo de captura.

Assim, define alguns "limitadores" no inicio da string, e no final usa `\1` para garantir que tens o mesmo:

```js
var testes = [
  '!abba!', '?abba?', '"ab ba"', "'abba'", 'xabbax', '!eu vou falhar?'
];

function filtro(str) {
  var match = str.match(/([!?'"x])(.*)(\1)/);
  if (!match) return '';
  return match[2];
}

console.log(testes.map(filtro));
```

Em casos onde se queira usar pares de simbolos para abrir e fechar uma região do texto, como `{}`, `()` ou `<>` poderia fazer-se assim:

```js
const testes = [
  '(abba)', '!eu vou falhar?', '{abba}', '<A>'
];
const separadores = ['{}', '\\(\\)', '<>'].map(char => {
  const abertura = char.slice(0, char.length / 2);
  const fecho = char.slice(char.length / 2);
  return `(${abertura})([^${fecho}]+)(${fecho})`
}).join('|');
console.log(separadores)
const regex = new RegExp(separadores);

function filtro(str) {

  var match = str.match(regex);
  match = match && match.filter(Boolean);
  if (!match) return '';
  return match[2];
}

console.log(testes.map(filtro));
```

Comment: Perfeito o uso da captura de grupo dentro do próprio regex. Não sabia que era possível isso. Obrigado.

Comment: Embora o AP tenha validado, me surgiu uma dúvida : como funcionar teu exemplo num texto corrido, fiz uma pequena alteração e veja o resultado : https://regex101.com/r/OouWLx/4

Comment: @MagicHat nesse caso de texto misturado a solução tem de ser mais complexa. Ou se separa tudo primeiro, ou então also como `['{', '\\?', '"', 'x'].map(char => \`(${char})([^${char}]+)(${char})\`).join('|')` para gerar a regex que ficaria assim: https://regex101.com/r/In0Ayw/1

Comment: Note que ainda assim pega a string dentro de caracteres onde seu fechamento é a abertura: `{fsdfsdff{`...

Comment: @MagicHat Exato, [perguntei sobre isso ao AP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198487/regex-abrir-e-fechar-com-o-mesmo-caractere-e-permitir-mais-de-um-tipo/198503?noredirect=1#comment407570_198487) pois o exemplo dele dava a entender isso, e [ele confirmou que o caractere de abertura e fecho seria o mesmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198487/regex-abrir-e-fechar-com-o-mesmo-caractere-e-permitir-mais-de-um-tipo/198503?noredirect=1#comment407579_198487).

Comment: Certamente há uma confusão, onde a compreensão de que `Se no inicio for ", deve terminar com o mesmo` seja aplicado também no caso de `{}[]()<>`... posso estar errado, mas não creio...Enfim não estou a testar sua capacidade, mas agora tenho mais certeza de que a questão não está clara, e apenas o AP poderia esclarecer...Bem relendo uma vez mais a questão creio que `Como fazer com que quando é aberto com {, permitir fechar apenas com }` esclarece. Vlw man..

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta, a resposta ainda serve. Mas seria interessante um exemplo de quando for aberto com `{` permitir não ele mesmo no final, mas um caractere diferente, no caso `}`, ainda sim sendo dinâmico para permitir mais de um par.

Comment: @RafaelMafra juntei essa opção à resposta.

Comment: @MagicHat juntei outra variante à resposta, depois da pergunta ser clarificada.

Answer (score 1):

Veja se é isto :

`/\(asdasd\)|{asdasd}/g`

[Explicação em inglês](https://regex101.com/r/OouWLx/2)

Comment: Obrigado pela responta. Essa é uma solução muito estática, e se ao invés ao invés de `{` e `(` fosse usado mais caracteres? Ou até mesmo um range. É inviável listar todos.

Comment: @RafaelMafra o que eu acho interessante é ver como algumas pessoas são boas em dar informações na hora de explicar o porque tal solução não lhe serve, mas na hora de fazer a pergunta não tem tal preocupação. Ao meu ver minha resposta atende perfeitamente ao que foi perguntado. Ao invés de colocar seu comentário, por que não edita sua pergunta?

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta para deixa-la mais clara. Mas foi o que eu disse, sua solução é funcional, porém eu queria uma forma dinâmica, como uso dos grupos que @Sergio mostrou.

Comment: Que grupos? Acho que você está confundindo  javascript com regex...
E no final o resultado da função js apresentada é semelhante ao que eu fiz...

Comment: Grupo que eu falo são os dados capturados entre parênteses.

Comment: Vejo que vc não me entendeu...mas se já tirou sua dúvida, boas.